# Can't find certain files.

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write a script that will look for a file and the script is running fine but is running as if it could never be found? However I know this file is there. It will run and also send multiple emails when I just want it to send one email instead of multiple. (I've removed my email and password for obvious reasons but the blank strings are my Email address/Password and I am aware of this.

This is my code:

```
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(bureau):
for filename in files:
    filename_no_ext, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    if ext.lower() == '.xls':
        num = filename.rsplit(" ")
        jnum = num[0]
        if num[0] in jobnums:
            master = ' '.join([jnum, "Master Box File List.xls"])
            for jobfolder in os.listdir(bureau):
                if jobfolder.startswith(jnum):
                    if os.path.exists(master):
                        print master
                    else:
                        fromaddr = ""
                        toaddr = ""

                        max_attempts = 5

                        login_success = False

                        for i in range(max_attempts):
                            try:
                                msg = MIMEMultipart()
                                msg['From'] = fromaddr
                                msg['To'] = toaddr
                                msg['Subject'] = "Scripting Email"

                                body = "This email is an automatic email part of a Python training excersise"

                                msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))    

                                server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
                                server.starttls()
                                server.login(fromaddr, "")
                                text = msg.as_string()

                                print "Signed In To Mailbox."

                                login_success = True

                                break

                            except:
                                print "Can't Sign In To Mailbox. Trying Again...."
                                time.sleep(0.5)
                                continue

                        if login_success:
                            server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
                            server.quit()
                            print "Email Sent."
                        else:
                            print "Can't Sign In To Mailbox."
```

Im not expecting this to be a huge error just something small that I can't see, cheers guys.

Comment: Please check indentation of second `for` statement at line #2.

Comment: which file can it not find, `"Master Box File List.xls"`? On which line does the script terminate? Do any of the print statements get executed? Basic debugging skills, trying `print` statements in various places, should help find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to take a wild guess that you don't actually mean to do

`for jobfolder in os.listdir(bureau):`

It looks like `bureau` is your top level directory.  It never changes in the code.  So for every file in your walk, you are running this for loop on the top level directory.  What are you actually trying to loop over?  If you're just checking for each file in the tree, you don't need another nested loop here, `os.walk` will already descend the full tree.